# Which of the following are the correct angle measures for angles 1 and 2 in the triangle shown below?

Tags: triangles

http://www.explorelearning.com/ELContent/gizmos/ELMath_Deliverable/ExplorationGuides/Geometry/images/EL_GEO_TriSum6.gif

A. mangle1 = 43°, mangle2 = 137°

B. mangle1 = 137°, mangle2 = 43°

C. mangle1 = 43°, mangle2 = 47°

D. mangle1 = 79°, mangle2 = 101°

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried so far to answer the problem?

Comment: What do you know about the sum of angles in **any** triangle? And what do you know about supplementary angles?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Consider the image and read the proof. For **every** triangle, the sum of it's angles is $180º$. Moreover

[image]

We know that in the last figure $\angle b+\angle d = 180º=\angle a + \angle c + \angle b\Rightarrow \angle d = \angle c + \angle a$.

Apply this general results to your triangle and you will obtain the answer.

Comment: Perhaps eliminating that $\;m\;$ in front of the angle sign will make things clearer. For example, compare $\;\angle d = \angle c +\angle a\;$ with $\;m\angle d=m\angle c +m\angle a\;$

Comment: Done. I wrote it that way because of the first image.